# How to do something after a specific period of time of a day in android?

Tags: java, android, loops, time

Suppose, I want to do something after every 4 hours of a day and I want to keep it running whilst my app isn't uninstalled. How can I do it programmatically in android? Please help!

Comment: use alarm manager for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a combination of Android's [AlarmManager Class](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/scheduling/alarms.html) and a [Service](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/services.html). Basically you should set a repeating or inexactRepeating alarm that runs your service every four hours. Also, don't forget to set a Broadcast Receiver up for when the user shuts off their phone. If you don't, all of your services will be cancelled.